# Error while exchanging partition in hive tables

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am trying to merge the incremental data with an existing hive table.

For testing I created a dummy table from the base table as below:

```
create base.dummytable like base.fact_table
```

The table: base.fact_table is partition based on `dbsource String`
When I checked the dummy table's DDL, I could see that the partition column is correctly defined.

```
PARTITIONED BY (                                                 |
|   `dbsource` string)
```

Then I tried to exchange one of the partition from the dummy table by dropping it first.

```
spark.sql("alter table base.dummy drop partition(dbsource='NEO4J')")
```

The partition: NEO4J has dropped successfully and I ran the exchange statement as below:

```
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE base.dummy EXCHANGE PARTITION (dbsource = 'NEO4J') WITH TABLE stg.inc_labels_neo4jdata")
```

The exchange statement is giving an error:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ValidationFailureSemanticException table is not partitioned but partition spec exists: {dbsource=NEO4J}
```

The table I am trying to push the incremental data is partitioned by `dbsource` and I have dropped it successfully.
I am running this from spark code and the config is given below:

```
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MERGER").set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "120s")
      .set("spark.network.timeout", "12000s")
      .set("spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed", "true")
      .set("spark.shuffle.compress", "true")
      .set("spark.shuffle.spill.compress", "true")
      .set("spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown", "true")
      .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "512m")
      .set("spark.serializer", classOf[org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer].getName)
      .set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true")
      .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false")
      .set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true")
      .set("spark.executor.instances", "4")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
      .set("spark.executor.cores", "5")
      .set("hive.merge.sparkfiles","true")
      .set("hive.merge.mapfiles","true")
      .set("hive.merge.mapredfiles","true")
```

> show create table base.dummy:

```
CREATE TABLE `base`.`dummy`(
`dff_id` bigint, 
`dff_context_id` bigint,  
`descriptive_flexfield_name` string,  
`model_table_name` string)
 PARTITIONED BY (`dbsource` string)
  ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
 OUTPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
 LOCATION  
'/apps/hive/warehouse/base.db/dummy'
 TBLPROPERTIES ( 
'orc.compress'='ZLIB')
```

> show create table stg.inc_labels_neo4jdata:

```
CREATE TABLE `stg`.`inc_labels_neo4jdata`(
`dff_id` bigint, 
`dff_context_id` bigint,  
`descriptive_flexfield_name` string,  
`model_table_name` string)
`dbsource` string)
  ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
 OUTPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
 LOCATION  
'/apps/hive/warehouse/stg.db/inc_labels_neo4jdata'
 TBLPROPERTIES ( 
'orc.compress'='ZLIB')
```

Could anyone let me know what the mistake I am doing here & what should I change inorder to successfully exchange the partition ?

Comment: Can you run `SHOW PARTITIONS stg.inc_labels_neo4jdata`?

Comment: There are no partitions on the staging table. It is resultant of a join between incremental & the existing table.

Comment: You want to move the partition from `base.dummy` to `stg.inc_labels_neo4jdata`?

Comment: Or the other way around? Anyway, both tables must have the same schema. Do you confirm that?

Comment: Please post `SHOW CREATE TABLE` of both tables.

Comment: Added the schemas of both the tables.

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue. You have no partition on `stg.inc_labels_neo4jdata`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on this error is that table `stg.inc_labels_neo4jdata` is not partitioned  as `base.dummy` and therefore there's no partition to move.

From [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExchangePartition):

> This statement lets you move the data in a partition from a table to
>   another table that has the same schema and does not already have that
>   partition.

You can check the Hive DDL Manual for [EXCHANGE PARTITION](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Exchange+Partition)

And the [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4095) where this feature was added to Hive. You can read:

> This only works if  and  have the
>   same field schemas and the same partition by parameters. If they do not
>   the command will throw an exception.

You basically need to have exactly the same schema on both `source_table` and `destination_table`.

Per your last edit, this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks Juma. You are correct. The schemas should be exact match. I thought the staging table need not contain 'partition' in the 'PARTITIONED BY' since syntax of exchange is on table level "WITH TABLE stg.inc_labels_neo4jdata"

Comment: Great stuff! I also think the Hive DDL Page should be updated to me more precise on this matter. It only states they should have the same schema. I think it should additionally say "including partitions".